# Dynamic Role Based Routing (React-Router)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-boilerplate

I am building an e-commerce related product and there are two types of users (customer & seller). Both types of user have their own homepage (totally different to each other). Now I want to route / on customer homepage if customer is logged-in or to seller homepage if seller account is logged-in. Otherwise it should route to landing page. How can I achieve this feature using `react-router` and [this boilerplate](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate)?

I tried to do something as follows (but it didn't work):

```
{
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      getComponent(nextState, cb) {
        let HomePagePath = 'containers/HomePage';
        if (customerLoggedIn) {
            HomePagePath = 'containers/CustomerHomePage';
       }
        const importModules = Promise.all([
          import(HomePagePath),
        ]);

        const renderRoute = loadModule(cb);

        importModules.then(([component]) => {
          renderRoute(component);
        });

        importModules.catch(errorLoading);
      },
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using React Boilerplate to do something similar. Here's the gist of it:

1. Define an `onEnter` function in routes.js

   onEnter: redirectToLogin,
   path: '/account',
   name: 'account',
   getComponent(nextState, cb) { ...
2. Import function in `routes.js`

   export default function createRoutes(store) {
     // Create reusable async injectors using getHooks factory
     const { injectSagas, redirectToLogin, redirectToDashboard } = getHooks(store);
3. Create your redirect function in `app/utils/hooks.js`. This is where you'd redirect based on user role.

   export function redirectToLogin(store) {
     // set pathname to enable redirect
     setPath();
     return (nextState, replace) => {
       if (!user(store)) {
         replace({
           pathname: '/',
           state: { nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname }
         });
       } else {
         if (user(store).account_status === 'closed') {
           replace({
             pathname: '/closedaccount',
             state: { nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname }
         });
         }
       }
     };
   }
4. Export redirect function from `app/utils/hooks.js`

   export function getHooks(store) {
     return {
       injectReducer: injectAsyncReducer(store),
       injectSagas: injectAsyncSagas(store),
       redirectToLogin: redirectToLogin(store),

Comment: But in this case, it will not be same route. Let me explain you once again: I have two home pages. One is for Seller and other is for customer. After a user logged in, it should route to its corresponding homepage. But URL must be same, that is, '/' 

Let's take facebook as an example. Landing/home page is different for loggedIn and not-loggedIn accounts.

Comment: Ah, if you want the same url then this solution won't do as it'll only redirect to e.g. /customer or /seller based on user role.

Answer (score 0):

I found an article [here](https://crazysigma.com/blogs/2017/04/16/role-based-routing-react-redux/), the gist of which i am writing here.
You can add a prop to you  component like so

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>

//BOD routes
<Route authorisedUsers={['KR']} path="/home" component={HomeContainer} />

//HR routes
<Route authorisedUsers={['HR']} path="/hrhome" component={HRDashboardContainer} />

//common routes    
<Route authorisedUsers={['KR', 'HR']} path="/notes" component={NotesContainer} />
```

and then add the following code in your  component, that renders on path='/'

```
Role based routing react redux
componentDidUpdate() {
  const { 
      children,  //Component to be rendered (HomeContainer if route = '/home')
      pathname: {location},  //location.pathname gives us the current url user is trying to hit. (with react router)
      profileId, //profileId required by profile page common to all user journeys.
      role } = this.props; 
  this.reRoute(role, this.props.children, location.pathname, ProfileId)
}

decideRoute(role, ProfileId) { //decide routes based on role
  if(role==='HR')
    return 'hrhome';
  else if(role==='KR')
    return 'home';
  else if(role==='USER'&&ProfileId)
    return 'profile/'+ProfileId;
  else
  return '/error';
}

isAuthorised(authorisedUsers, role) {
  return _.includes(authorisedUsers, role)
}

reRoute(role, children, path, ProfileId) {
  if(role===null && path!=='/') // user hit a different path without being authenticated first
  {
    hashHistory.replace('/');  //this is where we implemented login
    return;
  }
  let route = this.decideRoute(role, ProfileId)  //if role has already been fetched from the backend, use it to decide the landing page for each role.
  if(children)  // if we already are on one of the user journey screens ...
  {
    const authorisedUsers = children.props.route.authorisedUsers 
    if(!this.isAuthorised(authorisedUsers,role)) //... and the user is not allowed to view this page...
    hashHistory.replace(`/${route}/`);  //... redirect him to the home page corresponding to his role.
  }
  else
  hashHistory.replace(`/${route}/`);  // if the user has just logged in(still on / page or login page), and we know his role, redirect him to his home page.
}//if none of these holds true, user is allowed to go ahead and view the page
```

This essentially adds a gateway check that would work on all your containers and will direct you based on your role. Also, it wont allow you access if you somehow hit the wrong url.